# Mapping in Hibernate Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, mapping

I need to know how I can get one complete query in hibernate to get one list with games with full data with category and other game data translations.

Now, I have in Game two interfaces properties but Hibernate not permit mapped them, is normal, because interfaces are not persistent entities and Hibernate cant know it.

Some solution?. Thanks!

I have this BD structure:

[image: My EER]

My Hibernate Setup:

**Interfaces**

```
public interface GameInt {

    int getGame_id();

    void setGame_id(int game_id);

    String getTitle();

    void setTitle(String title);

    String getDescription();

    void setDescription(String description);

}

public interface CategoryInt{

    int getCategory_id();

    void setCategory_id(int category_id);

    String getName();

    void setName(String name);

    String getDescription();

    void setDescription(String description);

    void setCategory(Category category);

    Category getCategory();
}
```

**Persistent abstract superclasses**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class GameLang implements GameInt {

    private int game_id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    @Override
    @Id
    public int getGame_id() {
        return game_id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setGame_id(int game_id) {
        this.game_id = game_id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CategoryLang implements CategoryInt{

    private int category_id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Category category;

    @Override
    @Id
    public int getCategory_id() {
        return category_id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCategory_id(int category_id) {
        this.category_id = category_id;
    }

    @Override
    @Size(max = 50)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    @Size(max = 350)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

**And persistent final classes**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="es_games")
public class GameES extends GameLang implements Serializable {}

@Entity
@Table(name="en_games")
public class GameEN extends GameLang implements Serializable {}

@Entity
@Table(name = "es_categories")
public class CategoryES extends CategoryLang implements Serializable {}

@Entity
@Table(name = "en_categories")
public class CategoryEN extends CategoryLang implements Serializable {}

@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private boolean active;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "games")
public class Game implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private Integer categories_id;
    private Date date_start;
    private Date date_expire;
    private boolean active;
    private Integer game_size;
    private String position_one;
    private String position_two;
    private String position_three;
    private CategoryInt category;
    private GameInt game;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotNull
    public Integer getCategories_id() {
        return categories_id;
    }

    public void setCategories_id(Integer categories_id) {
        this.categories_id = categories_id;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getDate_start() {
        return date_start;
    }

    public void setDate_start(Date date_start) {
        this.date_start = date_start;
    }

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getDate_expire() {
        return date_expire;
    }

    public void setDate_expire(Date date_expire) {
        this.date_expire = date_expire;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Integer getGame_size() {
        return game_size;
    }

    public void setGame_size(Integer game_size) {
        this.game_size = game_size;
    }

    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    public String getPosition_one() {
        return position_one;
    }

    public void setPosition_one(String position_one) {
        this.position_one = position_one;
    }

    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    public String getPosition_two() {
        return position_two;
    }

    public void setPosition_two(String position_two) {
        this.position_two = position_two;
    }

    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    public String getPosition_three() {
        return position_three;
    }

    public void setPosition_three(String position_three) {
        this.position_three = position_three;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public CategoryInt getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(CategoryInt category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public GameInt getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public void setGame(GameInt game) {
        this.game = game;
    }
}
```

**FINAL CONCLUSION.**

How I mean this is imposible to do, to resolve question is necesary use HQL.

In this case, I built this POJO.

```
public class GameCategoryByLang {

    private Game game;
    private GameInt gameLang;
    private CategoryInt categoryLang;

    public GameCategoryByLang(Game game, GameInt gameLang, CategoryInt categoryLang) {
        this.game = game;
        this.gameLang = gameLang;
        this.categoryLang = categoryLang;
    }

    public Game getGame() {
        return game;
    }

    public void setGame(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public GameInt getGameLang() {
        return gameLang;
    }

    public void setGameLang(GameInt gameLang) {
        this.gameLang = gameLang;
    }

    public CategoryInt getCategoryLang() {
        return categoryLang;
    }

    public void setCategoryLang(CategoryInt categoryLang) {
        this.categoryLang = categoryLang;
    }
}
```

And implement it with data with this HQL.

```
String hql = "select new my.package.GameCategoryByLang(g, gx, c) from Game g, Game" + lang.toUpperCase() + " gx, Category" + lang.toUpperCase() + " c WHERE g.id = gx.game_id and g.id = c.category_id";
```

Comment: I know it is an off-topic, but could I ask the name of the UML tool you used?

Comment: Is not any special UML tool, Image was made with MySQL Workbench UML tool.

Answer (score 1):

Well the database schema is terrible - what are you going to do when you expand to russia, china, india?? you should have one table for category and have a column to distinguish between countries, same for games. Then the queries will be much easier.

Comment: Yes, but not is well solution for me, because not all categoryes or all games, or all querys of games must be internationalized, each category, or game... will be internationalized in some languages. This solution is better for me, each internationalized db table only have the necesary data internationalized. All aplication is development with interfaces and is totally dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Is better to do next: `es_games`, `en_games` change on one table - `all_games` with field `lang`

next you can do one superclass

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Inheritance
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "all_games")
@javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn(name = "LANG")
@javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue("nknown")
@org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorFormula("case when LANG in "
+ "('es', 'en') "
+ "then LANG else 'unknown' end")
public class AllGames implements java.io.Serializable{  

// ..  all general getters and setters

}
```

and make subclasses

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue("en")
public class GameEN extends AllGames implements java.io.Serializable
{  
// ..  
}  
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue("es")
public class GameES extends AllGames implements java.io.Serializable
{  
// ..  
}
```

The same you can do with `categories`

Comment: HI friend, this is powerfull to other situations (I have learnt it), but in this case, is not full internationalization to all games, so I want that is not good beacuse games table will increase faster. I am grateful very much with your interest.